# Fusion Table - Zoom to Boundaries of Region

Tags: google-maps, google-fusion-tables

I am creating a multiregion and district map which you can see here:
http://vciregionmap.com/new/

It used this Fusion Table in the new version:
https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?snapid=S587803AEqk

It works great, the only thing it does not do and used to do in the old version - the code is in there but stopped working about 8 months ago.

I need the legend to is zoom to the bounds of the region and district that you choose.

I am unsure of how to get the map to zoom upon clicking the legend - I think I may be able to do without drawing the bounds of regions and districts, but the zoom (as you see) is really needed.

Here is what I am having issues with . . 
Map View 1 - Show all 5 Regions with outline on bounds of Region.
Map View 2- Zoom into Region and show bounds for each district.
Map View 3 - Zoom into District bounds showing only markers for that district.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is only "selecting" one column (Latitude), but the callback routine expects 2:

```
      parseFloat(response.getDataTable().getValue(i, 0)),
      parseFloat(response.getDataTable().getValue(i, 1)));
```

That is why you get this javascript error:

```
Uncaught Error: Invalid column index 1. Should be an integer in the range [0-0].
```

This [thread in the fusion tables users group  from 6 months ago](https://groups.google.com/group/fusion-tables-users-group/browse_frm/thread/2926bf052aa5f237/f76732392cd86351?lnk=gst&q=gviz+query+fusiontableslayer+geocodezip#f76732392cd86351) explains the problem and includes the fix ([this post](https://groups.google.com/group/fusion-tables-users-group/msg/f76732392cd86351)).

[I think this is what you are trying to do](http://www.geocodezip.com/vciregionmap_com_new_20120724a.html)

Comment: thank you very much - I think I got things to zoom in on the results now (vciregionmap.com/new) - I had changed up the code a bit and seemed to have torked things up quite a bit. I checked back to the old samples.

Would you happen to know how to use the same response to return the bounds for a region (a set of districts) vs. a single district ? 

I am also looking to see if I can outline the regions and districts, I am assuming from what I have seen I would have to tent pole them in order of the outlines needed? Never used polygons or shapes in any way any good place to look for this info?

Comment: What are the shapes of the regions/districts?  If the "regions" are divided by US state or on US state boundaries, those polygons are available, [here is one example using public data in FusionTables](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_FusionTables_query_sidebarF_local.html?country=United%20States%20of%20America)

Comment: Also, a query for the region ([REGION = Northeast](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_FusionTablesLayer_linktoA.html?lat=39.689872&lng=-78.709861&zoom=5&type=m&tableid=4592563&tablequery=SELECT%20Latitude%20FROM%204592563%20WHERE%20%27REGION%27%20%3D%20%27Northeast%27)) rather than the district will allow you to use the existing code to zoom to the region.

Comment: Thank you so much, the states example will help greatly, but forgive me, but I have no idea how to integrate that query for region into the existing one that I have for district at vciregionmap.com/new/

Comment: Do I re-create a new function using Region vs. District, like below? I seem to have been doing incorrectly to date. Thanks.

`function changeRegion(term) {
  layer.setOptions({query:{select:'Latitude', /* was 'Latitude,Longitude', used to work… */
                           from:FT_TableID,
                           where:"Region = "+term,
                           }

 });
`

Comment: The [example I provided in my comment above](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_FusionTablesLayer_linktoA.html?lat=39.689872&lng=-78.709861&zoom=5&type=m&tableid=4592563&tablequery=SELECT%20Latitude%20FROM%204592563%20WHERE%20%27Region%27%20%3D%20%27Northeast%27) used to work, I just fixed the query in this post (looks like you changed the name of the "Region" column).  I can't read code in comments, either put it on your map or edit your question to include it.

Comment: sorry about the comments in the code - I think it was not supposed to be there or I trimmed them out. The thing is I dont know how to have the query for District (for those numbers) and Region for those listed - in the same page. I replaced the district query for Region and it is located here: http://www.vciregionmap.com/new - but I dont know hot to combine the two in one script.

Comment: You need to create two separate functions (or at least that is how I would probably do it), one to query for district (and use the zoomTo callback) and one to query for region (using the same call back).  Currently your page has a javascript error "Uncaught ReferenceError: Northeast is not defined", I suspect that needs to be a string ('Northeast') when you call the changeQuery function.

Comment: I had tried that, but I think I did not know enough about what was needed as far as all the parts of the script for a new functions.

I named the new function changeRegion and put it in place with the region links calling that function vs. the changeQuery - I am getting an error, but it looks like it zooms to the area, kinda. Ideas on what I have wrong? http://www.vciregionmap.com/new/

Comment: You don't need to load the visualization API again, it is already loaded, you also don't need to redefine the zoomTo function, it should be the same.  All you should need is the changeRegion function, and call that when the user click on the region names in the sidebar.

Comment: Also, you don't need a second initialize function.  Your queries need to be for "Region = '"+term+"'" (putting ' around the Region "name" since it is a string.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, so for the function it is:

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, so for the function it is: 

`function changeRegion(term) {
  layer.setOptions({query:{select:'Latitude', /* was 'Latitude,Longitude', used to work… */
                           from:FT_TableID,
                           where:"Region = "'+term+',}
                   });}                           
  var queryText = encodeURIComponent("SELECT 'Latitude', 'Longitude' FROM "+FT_TableID+" WHERE Region = "'+term+');
  var query = new google.visualization.Query('http://www.google.com/fusiontables/gvizdata?tq='  + queryText);
  
  query.send(zoomTo);`
?

Comment: feels like it is so close, but I am not getting errors that would point to the issue, http://www.vciregionmap.com/new/

Comment: At least this needs to change: where:"Region = '+term+' -- should be where:"Region = '"+term+"'"

Comment: fixed that but the same issue persists with zooming to fit - also wanted to ensure the queryText line should NOT have a double quote prior to Region:  
`var queryText = encodeURIComponent("SELECT 'Latitude', 'Longitude' FROM "+FT_TableID+" WHERE Region = '"+term+"'");`  
But the Function should:  
    
`function changeRegion(term) {
  layer.setOptions({query:{select:'Latitude', /* was 'Latitude,Longitude', used to work… */
                           from:FT_TableID,
                           where:"Region =  '"+term+"'"}
                         
                   });}`

Comment: thank you - I added it, the correct syntax, but zoom to region is not working, this error shows - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null. at http://www.vciregionmap.com/new/

Comment: GeoCodeZip -
Thanks, I did not see the updated example.You sir, are awesome. I thank you all you help, as painful as it was I am sure. If you could point me in the direction to find something that would outline and fill a Region area that we are using in the query, I would be forever in your debt.

Comment: Looks to me like you could use state boundaries as I suggested above.

Comment: Thanks! You are a great help, I have now been asked to do this -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11696084/filter-current-value-of-a-fusion-table-query :(