# Reset Button - creating a function and a button to make it works

Tags: javascript, google-fusion-tables

I'm trying to create a reset button in a Fusion Tables Map, to once it is clicked all the markers show up. But something is not working on it. Please take a look:

HERE'S THE ENTIRE CODE:

Actually I tryed to "mimic" the function initialize() from the layer10 part in the function clearBox(). I also tryed to use the method reset(), but it didn't work too.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#map-canvas { width:500px; height:600px; }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var map;
var layerl0;
function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-30.070876662388095, -51.1907958984375),
    zoom: 12,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });
  layerl0 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    query: {
      select: "'ENDERECO'",
      from: '3385625'
    },
    map: map
  });
}
function changeMapl0() {
  var searchString = document.getElementById('search-string-l0').value.replace(/'/g, "\\'");
  layerl0.setOptions({
    query: {
      select: "'ENDERECO'",
      from: 3385625,
      where: "'TIPO' = '" + searchString + "'"
    }
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

//Function to be activated by the reset button
function clearBox() {
document.getElementById('search-string-l0').value = "";
  layerl0 = google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    query: {
      select: "'ENDERECO'",
      from: '3385625'
    },
  });
}

 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<div style="margin-top: 10px;">
  <label>Tipo</label>
  <select id="search-string-l0" onchange="changeMapl0 (this.value);">
    <option value="">--Select--</option>
    <option value="Comidas variadas">Comidas variadas</option>
    <option value="Restaurante">Restaurante</option>
    <option value="Bar">Bar</option>
    <option value="Hotel">Hotel</option>
    <option value="Shopping Center">Shopping Center</option>
    <option value="Teatro">Teatro</option>
    <option value="Igreja">Igreja</option>
    <option value="Museu">Museu</option>
    <option value="Espaço de Cultura">Espaço de Cultura</option>
  </select><br/>
<input type="button" onclick="clearBox()" value="Reset Map" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What isn't happening? To "reset" a select element, you don't use .value, you use .selectedIndex, and set it to 0. Take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/6WgFu/

Comment: There is no "map" variable in your code.  How are you initializing the map?  How are you initializing the FusionTablesLayer, what does your initial query of the look like?  You probably just need to re-run that (like the example I posted).

Comment: What is the changeMapl0 function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need to reset your query like [this map](http://www.vciregionmap.com/) from this [recent post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11572421/fusion-table-zoom-to-boundaries-of-region)

Looking at your complete code, the simplest way to make it work is to change your reset function to just change the query, not recreate the FusionTablesLayer:

change:

```
function clearBox() {
document.getElementById('search-string-l0').value = "";
  layerl0 = google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    query: {
      select: "'ENDERECO'",
      from: '3385625'
    },
  });
}
```

to:

```
function clearBox() {
document.getElementById('search-string-l0').value = "";
  layerl0.setOptions({
    query: {
      select: "'ENDERECO'",
      from: '3385625'
    }
  });
}
```

Note: I also removed an extraneous comma that would probably cause issues in IE.

[Working Example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_FusionTables_resetMapA.html)

Comment: Yes, that what I want to do! By the way, great map!

Comment: Actually, I don't want to reset the select form. I want to reset the markers on the map!

Comment: Updated based on the complete code you uploaded, including a working example

Comment: Thanks a lot! I believe that the code was missing the .setOptions method.

Comment: Sure! How can I do that? I'm a begginer here.

Comment: It is the check mark (not the upvote), means the answer worked for you,  I think you as the asker are the only one that can accept the answer, but I am fairly new as well.