# Filter current value of a Fusion Table Query

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-fusion-tables

With much help, I have created this Map with data from Queries to a Fusion Table.

http://www.vciregionmap.com

I am now being asked to add a brand filter into the map that filters and persists the filtered value that is selected, as the user chooses new Regions and Districts.

So if I choose - Region > NorthEast and then select Bentley, only those Bentley locations would be shown and if I then switched to Region SouthEast, District 61, it would still show only Bentley locations, until I reset the map.

I have the brand filter in a select menu and have the filter working, but not by current location or values and I dont know how to reset the brand select to return all brands. I had a version of this working with different code here: http://vciregionmap.com/_old/

This is the function I am using now:

```
 function filterBrand(term) {
 layer.setOptions({query:{select:'Brand',
                       from:FT_TableID,
                       where:"Brand = '"+term+"'"
                       }

});
var queryStr = "SELECT 'Brand', 'Brand' FROM "+FT_TableID+" WHERE Brand = '"+term+"'";

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('brand-select'),
        'change', function() {
          updateMap(layer, tableId, Brand);
    });

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: Looks like you have the main functionality working

Comment: Right - I can filter by Brand, but I dont know how to Filter by Brand for the locations showing the current Region View or current District view - now it shows all of them and resets the brand query results when you choose another region or district. 


I have tried a few samples of code to get the current value for Region and or District, but no luck. Something like this sample: http://lop.im/rvSY9

Comment: You need to do something like the refreshFusion(), but modified for your area query (Region or District) and your brand query.

Comment: I tried something like:
function refreshFusion() {
var qry = "SELECT Brand, 'Status' FROM " + FT_TableID;
var Region = document.getElementById('Region').value;
var status = document.getElementById('District').value;
var filters = [];
if(interest != '') {
filters.push("'Region' CONTAINS '" + Brand + "'");
}
if(status != '') {
filters.push("'District' CONTAINS '" + Brand + "'");
}
if(filters.length > 0) {
qry += " WHERE " + filters.join(" AND ");
}
layer.setQuery(qry);
}
Not sure how to capture the current Region or District values on the table and filter then against the new brand query

Comment: Hey -

So I can not figure this one out - I know I had a working version that used jQuery and not the code we have created to date.
http://vciregionmap.com/_old/
he select box worked to filter by brand, but did not zoom due to the same original issue I had with the page calling 2 values and expecting 3 in the response.

The issue is I didn't write this version: 

And I do not know how to integrate the function into the new version, I have tried to write a refreshFusion sample with no luck.